# how to Python re.findall print only capturing matches?

Tags: python, regex

In this post

[Regular expression negative lookbehind of non-fixed length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093474/regular-expression-negative-lookbehind-of-non-fixed-length)

the answerer says, to match things only to ignore them.  I want to use that example, but I want to print only the matches that are not ignored.

Comment: If you want only `bar`, why do you need to match `foo`? Do you want it to be before `bar` to match `bar`?

Comment: of course the real example is more complex, I just gave you an SSCCE

Comment: Perhaps we need a slightly less simple example? I can't fathom why I'd want to match something I didn't want to keep.

Comment: @MarkGaleck that question contains an answer by me using Negative Lookahead. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I can't explain that better.  I apologize.  Thank you everybody, I appreciate.  This is embarrasing.

Comment: `re.findall(r'\b(?!foo)bar', 'foo bar foo bar')` ??

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure that, `foo` should be followed by `bar` and if you are only interested in `bar`, then you can use look-behind assertion, like this

```
re.findall("(?<=foo )bar", "foo bar")
# ['bar']
```

Instead of `bar`, if you want to match anything followed by `foo`, you can do

```
re.findall("(?<=foo ).*", "foo google")
# ['google']
```

Comment: I am not explaining it correctly.  Let me try again

Answer (score 1):

This will leave empty items in the list. But for what I assume you are asking, you can use the alternation operator in context placing what you want to exclude on the left, ( *saying throw this away, it's garbage* ) and place what you want to match in a capturing group on the right side to only print the captured matches.

```
>>> re.findall(r'foo|(bar)', 'foo bar foo bar')
['', 'bar', '', 'bar']
```