# Complicated regex to match anything NOT within quotes

Tags: regex

I have this regex which scans a text for the word `very`: `(?i)(?:^|\W)(very)[\W$]` which works. My goal is to upgrade it and avoid doing a match if very is within quotes, standalone or as part of a longer block.

Now, I have this other regex which is matching anything NOT inside curly quotes: `(?<![\S"])([^"]+)(?![\S"])` which also works.

My problem is that I cannot seem to combine them. For example the string:

`Fred Smith very loudly said yesterday at a press conference that fresh peas will "very, very defintely not" be served at the upcoming county fair`. In this bit we have 3 instances of `very` but I'm only interested in matching the first one and ignore the whole Smith quotation.

Comment: Set a bounty for it. I'd like to see how to match a string that does not come after an odd number of quotation marks and before at least one quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is kind of tricky to handle with a regular expression. It's difficult to determine whether you are inside a quote. Your second regex is not effective as it only ignores the first `very` that is directly to the right of the quote and still matches the second one.

Drawing inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093474/regular-expression-negative-lookbehind-of-non-fixed-length), that in turn references another answer that describes how to [regex match a pattern unless ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between) I can capture the matches you want.

The basic idea is to use alternation `|` and match all the things you don't want  and then finally match (and capture) what you do want in the final clause. Something like this:

```
"[^"]*"|(very)
```

We match quoted strings in the first clause but we don't capture them in a group and then we match (and capture) the word `very` in the second clause. You can find this match in the captured group. How you reference a captured group depends on your regex environment.

See this [regex101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/LlW6zm/1) for a test case.

Comment: I see the words inside curly quotes still being matched. I need to ignore anything inside there.

Comment: The way this approach works is with the capturing group. You actively match the quoted string, but you don't capture it (no capturing group), you only use a capturing group for `very` and then you can reference that. Referencing a capturing group depends on your regex environment but I'm not sure what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This regex

```
(?i)(?<!(((?<DELIMITER>[ \t\r\n\v\f]+)(")(?<FILLER>((?!").)*))))\bvery\b(?!(((?<FILLER2>((?!").)*)(")(?<DELIMITER2>[ \t\r\n\v\f]+))))
```

could work under two conditions:

- your regex engine allows unlimited lookbehind
- quotes are delimited by spaces

Try it on http://regexstorm.net/tester